# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar los datos de un formulario en otra página?

Tags: php, html, formularios

En index.html tengo el formulario, al presionar "Enviar" me manda a "enviodemail.php" y este simplemente muestra una mensaje de "Datos capturados correctamente". Mi pregunta es, en otro archivo ("registros.php") tengo que mostrar los datos que se ingresan en el formulario, ¿cómo puedo hacer eso?
No sé cómo relacionar que al momento de dar click en enviar, aparte de que me redireccione a "enviodemail" y muestre el mensaje, en la parte de "registros" deben de estar los datos que se ingresaron al formulario.
Tengo esto en index.html:

```
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="titulo">Título de la obra *</label>
              <input id="titulo" type="text" required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9áéíóú ]+" name="titulo" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fecha">Fecha de creación *</label>
              <input id="fecha" type="date" name="fecha" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="tecnica">Técnica *</label>
              <input id="tecnica" type="text" required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9áéíóú ]+" name="tecnica" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="seudonimo">Seudónimo *</label>
              <input id="seudonimo" type="text" required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9áéíóú ]+" name="seudonimo" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="edad">Edad *</label>
              <input id="edad" type="number" name="edad" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="ciudad">Ciudad y/o estado de residencia *</label>
              <input id="ciudad" type="text" required pattern="[A-Za-z0-9áéíóú ]+" name="ciudad" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="telefono">Teléfono de casa con lada</label>
              <input id="telefono" type="tel" name="telefono" name="telefono" class="form-control" >
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="celular">Celular *</label>
              <input id="celular" type="tel" name="celular" name="celular" class="form-control" requireds>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="correo">Correo electrónico de contacto *</label>
              <input id="correo" type="email" name="correo" class="form-control" required>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="sitio">Sitio web, blog o sitio de internet de quien se inscribe</label>
              <input id="sitio" type="text" name="sitio" class="form-control">
            </div>



            <input id="submit_button" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" />

            <input id="delete_button" name="borrar" type="reset" value="Borrar" />


            <div id="resultado"></div>

          </form>
```

Y en registros.php sólo tengo esto:

```
<?php 
$titulo =   isset( $_POST['titulo'] ) ? $_POST['titulo'] : '';
$fecha =   isset( $_POST['fecha'] ) ? $_POST['fecha'] : '';
$tecnica  =   isset( $_POST['tecnica'] ) ? $_POST['tecnica'] : '';
$seudonimo =  isset( $_POST['seudonimo'] ) ? $_POST['seudonimo'] : '';
$edad =  isset( $_POST['edad'] ) ? $_POST['edad'] : '';
$ciudad =  isset( $_POST['ciudad'] ) ? $_POST['ciudad'] : '';
$telefono =  isset( $_POST['telefono'] ) ? $_POST['telefono'] : '';
$celular =  isset( $_POST['celular'] ) ? $_POST['celular'] : '';
$correo =  isset( $_POST['correo'] ) ? $_POST['correo'] : '';
$sitio =  isset( $_POST['sitio'] ) ? $_POST['sitio'] : '';
$contenido = '
                    <html>
                    <head>
                        <title></title>
                    </head>
                    <bod
                        <p>Titulo: '.$titulo.' </p>
                        <p>Técnica: '.$tecnica.' </p>

                         <hr>

                    </body>
                    </html>';
echo $contenido;                        
?>
```

Comment: Intenta hacer un include en el archivo `enviodeemail.php ` del archivo `registros.php`, `include '../registros.php'`

Comment: lo que puedes hacer es usar el envío de Ajax con jQuery para traernos datos de registros.php y luego ir al de email.

Answer (score 2):

creo que el compañero no va desencaminado.
puedes hacer un evento en el boton de enviar. Este manda la info a enviodeemail.php.
Este PHP tiene que devolver la misma info.
Despues con AJAX, y en el callback, lo mandas a registros.php.
Algo asi:

```
$("#submit_button").click(function (e){

    $.ajax({
            url: 'enviodeemail.php',
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response) {
                    //Aqui el response son los datos en formato JSON
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'registros.php',
                        data: response,
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function (response) {
                            console.log("done")
                        }, dataType: "json"
                    });

            }, dataType: "json"
    });
})
```

Ya me dices si te vale! ;)